# mono Thread.Sleep(int) thrown System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, mono

I have the following problem:

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting");
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
int delay = 1 * 60 * 1000;
int waitTime = delay - (int)(DateTime.Now.Second * 1000);
int time;
Console.WriteLine("PRE-Sleep");
Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
Console.WriteLine("AFTER-Sleep");
```

Output is:

```
Starting
PRE-Sleep
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Changing Thread.Sleep(waitTime) to Thread.Sleep(1) produce the following output:

```
Starting
PRE-Sleep
AFTER-Sleep
```

And everything works fine.

How can it be?

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       altstack
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  x86
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Edit:
Code works fine under Windows using Xamarin

Comment: where do you run this code? the main method of you app? Is it a console application?

Comment: Why do you need to cast `DateTime.Now.Second` to `int`? It should already *be* an `int`. I find this suspicious.

Comment: the int cast is a typo, the code is executed under a thread created by the main method, and yes it's a console app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Founded:
it wasn't relative to Thread.Sleep

The app read a cfg file that under linux was misslinked.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

solved the problem.

Comment: So what's going on here? You have two choices: 1) Delete the question. 2) Explain how you solved the problem even if it is not related to `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: Ty Alvin,i've edited the solution, in case isn't adequate let me know and i'll delete the question